# iOS 6 Reset All Settings issue with saved BLE peripheral UUID

Tags: ios, ios6, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am developing a BLE app on iOS where I saved to NSUSerDefaults the CBPeripheral UUID after a connection is formed to the BLE accessory. This way, if the app is re-launched later on, and the BLE accessory is not turned-on or out of range, I can display the BLE accessory in the App's UI as "not found". If the BLE accessory is then turn-on or the user becomes within BLE range, the app will automatically connect to the BLE accessory.

The issue I am facing is that in iOS 6, if the user does a Settings -> General -> Reset -> Reset All Settings, the next time the app is launched the BLE accessory will have a different CBPeripheral UUID. This causes problems in my App and UI as then two BLE accessories will be displaying: one for the new UUID and one for the old UUID (that the user had connected to in the past but that no longer exists).

Is there a way for the app to tell if the user has done a "Reset All Settings" so that I can clear my list of connected BLE accessories (UUIDs) that I have saved into preferences?

Or any other ideas of how to deal in this situation?

Thanks,

Comment: At least, does anybody know in which iOS version does the "Reset All Settings" behavior about erasing the UUIDs stops? In iOS 7, even if you "Reset All Settings", the UUIDs are maintained.

Answer (score 1):

Store the UUID's in the Keychain instead of NSUserDefaults. An app's keychain will be erased when the user performs a Reset All Settings, so either your UUID's will disappear.

You could also just store some arbitrary flag in the Keychain, if you really wanted to use NSUserDefaults for the UUID's. In that case, you'd just check if the flag was present in the keychain when your app starts. If not, then trash the UUID's and create a new flag.

Comment: Thanks! I think this will work. Have used the Keychain before, but did not think about it for this occasion :D.

Comment: Well, this did not work. The app's keychain is not being erased when the user performs a Reset All Settings. So I still have the same problem. Any other ideas?

Comment: It may be related to how I am using the keychain, i am currently using it like i would to store a password. Can you point me to an example of using the keychain where it would be erased if the user "reset all settings"?

Answer (score 1):

As adpalumbo suggested, use a Keychain to store your UDID.

This [UICkeychain](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/UICKeyChainStore)  library is a good one and easy-to-use.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make a compression statement in every startup that check if the UDID is changed or not and you gotta save the current_udid in sqlite for example and application checks every time once it noticed that something change you can implement what you want ..

hopefully that will help